# How can I make a text box that when filled out and hit enter, checks a box by the code that was typed in?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I make a text box that when filled out and hit enter, checks a box by the code that was typed in?

There are multiple fields in each row in the database; Accountability check box, Name, ID number, address, , etc... Respectively. I want to have a split form that has fields to edit view each profile and then a table with all the data on the bottom. I want to have a box that when the ID number is typed into will check the box for accountability, and then I want to have a button that will uncheck all of the accountability check boxes to reset it.

I will make ID cards with bar codes and a scanner that will be set up to hit "enter" after the code, so I want it to run continuously.

I am very used to Excel and VBA but I have never used Access, So I am trying to get a start on it.

Thank you for any help and if you have any recommendations on how to make this simpler or better I would appreciate it!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the text box name is txtTextBox and check box chkCheckBox, then use After Update event of txtTextBox with code like:

```
chkCheckBox = False
If Len(NZ(txtTextBox)) > 0 Then chkCheckBox = True
```